MacBook white 13" mid 2007 not booting - how to find if power adapter or MacBook are defective?
I have an old MacBook White mid 2007, which worked slowly but flawlessly so far.
MacBook2,1
A1181
Now it suddenly stopped working:

it does not boot any more
and the green/red LED in the connector of the power supply stays dark
the battery is empty (1 LED flashing)

How can I find out if the problem is

a defective power adapter (A1184)
or the electronics of the MacBook itself?

Unfortunately, I don't have a second power adapter nor do I know anyone who could have it. Can I measure the voltage output of the power adapter to check?

How old is the battery?

@nohillside I'll have to check, but is was replaced some years ago... BTW, if the battery would be dead, the Macbook would still be able to boot with power supply, wouldn't it?

"some years" is probably old enough to consider the battery to just have died. Don't know about the 2007, but usually the power is run "through the battery", so without one it won't work.

Thank you - I see. But the battery exists and one LED is flashing, if I push the button on the battery, so at least there is some life in it...

I understand this. But basically it's the power supply, the battery or the main board. Neither of which can be diagnosed remotely, you have to replace them one by one. I would start with the battery.

TBH, I would probably "call it", as the doctors say. Any money that you might spend on components could be better spent towards a newer Mac, like a 2015 MBP or a Retina MB Air (2018+). A 17-year-old laptop is verging on retro-computing! I suspect that lots of websites won't work on it, for starters.

@benwiggy I see your point. My child used it with a recent Linux OS for Libre Office and web research, and it seemed to work so far...
I prefer fixing old things, as long as they work, and avoiding waste. But sure, it might be the right moment for a less old hardware... we'll see.

I have a late 2011 MacbookPro. I use a 60W MagSafe Power Adapter with "T" style connector which according to https://support.apple.com/en-us/109509  is the same as the one you should be using. Please be careful and do this at your own risk to your Mac charger. METHOD 1 : Here is a link to the pin-out of the charger connector. http://static.righto.com/images/magsafe/magsafe_connector_labels.png . If you are very careful using a multi-meter you can hold the negative probe to the metal 'square-donut' outside part of the connector and the positive terminal of the multi-meter to either of the 'power' terminals. DO NOT short out the ground and power terminals with the positive multi-meter probe (it is very easy to do as they are tiny and right next to each other!)I would recommend putting some tape or hollowed out cable insulation around the ground terminal to be safe, while you are making contact with the power terminal. Also take note and remember there are 2 of each (Power and ground), again be patient and careful!!! NOTE : The square-donut metal part of the connector is also ground and is eaiser to use than one of the tiny ground terminals.
Then you can be sure if your charger still works or not!
METHOD 2: Ask me for this if you're still not having any luck.
